# Android: Change MenuItem text on app startup

Tags: android, menu

How can i change the text of a MenuItem before the corresponding menu was actually shown to the user? (The text corresponds to a previously saved setting, that should be loaded again at app start)

I'm creating the menu like this:

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);        
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {   
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.dosomething:
                ;
                break;

            case R.id.dosomething2:
                ;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So how to change "R.id.dosomething" on app startup?

Answer (score 0):

why don't u save the string in sqlite db or save it in preferences and when application lanched next time you can directly refer the string from preference or sqlite.

Just a thought.

Comment: would be ok but a bit overkill ;)